# Prioritize webhost for a domain?

Tags: web-hosting, domains, dns, subdomain

I have a sub domain( I do not own the domain) but using Cpanel I am able to set A, NS, Cname records for a sub domain. What I want to do is to associate the subdomain with two webhost and prioritize them so that if the one with higher priority is down then the second webhost is used instead.

Now I have already set the NS records for both webhosts to the sub domain but I do not know if there exists a priority.

How do accomplish this task if it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With A records, you cannot set a priority.  In fact, some name servers will give out the IPs in a round-robin fashion.  While others will send both IPs and the browser will try the first one.

What you need is a DNS fail-over service.  This will not provide real-time redundancy but does help.

By combining a short time to live and a system that will automatically switch to your backup A record, you can get close to what you desire.

DNS Made Easy offers such a service:

http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/services/dns-failover-system-monitoring/

I am sure there are other vendors but I've trusted our DNS to them for several years with few issues.

Answer (score 0):

No... No.. it seems you cant do that. If you point 2 different IP, I'm afraid it will make instability on your site, when you ping it, sometimes it will show IP address A, and sometimes it will show IP address B.

Comment: both the ip's have essentially the same data, I only want to prioritize the prefrence of selection, so it does not matter to me if different ip's are being pinged to